# Why my admin route is showing 404 and URLs include server.php?

Tags: magento2, admin, url, local

I already checked everything, my remote server is working properly by my local showed up this issue, as you can see in this image below.

[image: ValetPlus Magento2 admin 404 server.php]

I don't know if it's related to my local environment using [Valet+](https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus) or if it's something related with my Magento configuration.

How could I figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a [Valet+ issue](https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus/issues/66), to fix it you have to change your Magento 2 admin option. You can use this command below to enable the **URL Rewrites** via CLI.

```
php bin/magento config:set web/seo/use_rewrites 1
```